# Why my covariate in a glm give me NA as a result?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, time-varying-covariate

I have mammal track data collected monthly from 5 different trails -whit different lengths- for two years. I want to know if there are specific trails that have more species and if that differences are explain by month or year, and since trails have different lengths, I am using trail length as a covariate. 
I am new using glm, but here is my code

```
Model1 <- glm(S~Sendero + Year + Mes + SenDist , family=poisson, data = S)


----------


S: species richness
Sendero: trail
Mes: month
SenDist: trail lenght
Then I summary the results of the model with summary (Model1) and got the following results:


----------


glm(formula = S ~ Sendero + Year + Mes + SenDist, family = poisson, 
    data = S)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.67017  -0.59115   0.02955   0.52141   2.05260  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 47.38031   29.31333   1.616  0.10602    
SenderoSP   -0.26356    0.08954  -2.944  0.00324 ** 
SenderoSRM  -0.61432    0.10144  -6.056 1.40e-09 ***
SenderoSRP   0.06661    0.07994   0.833  0.40471    
SenderoSRS   0.02315    0.08256   0.280  0.77920    
SenderoSS    0.53699    0.07241   7.416 1.21e-13 ***
Year        -0.02292    0.01454  -1.576  0.11503    
MesAG        0.57564    0.12628   4.559 5.15e-06 ***
MesDI        0.51920    0.12337   4.208 2.57e-05 ***
MesEN        0.37557    0.12675   2.963  0.00305 ** 
MesFE        0.13226    0.13127   1.008  0.31367    
MesJUL       0.40303    0.12317   3.272  0.00107 ** 
MesJUN       0.42325    0.12870   3.289  0.00101 ** 
MesMA        0.18039    0.13105   1.376  0.16867    
MesMAY       0.07674    0.13588   0.565  0.57224    
MesNO        0.66681    0.12519   5.326 1.00e-07 ***
MesOC        0.53225    0.12371   4.302 1.69e-05 ***
MesSE        0.60410    0.12243   4.934 8.04e-07 ***
SenDist           NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 500.23  on 353  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 219.01  on 336  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1435

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4


----------
```

But I don´t understand why I got the NA for the SenDist (trail lenght), Any ideas?.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. Yes, it has code in R, but the question would arise regardless of what software was being used.

Comment: Can it be, that the length of the trail is already fixed, when the trail is named? Is the length of SP always the same and the length aof SRM always the same and the length of SRP always the same?

Comment: The lenght of each trail (SRM, SP, etc) is always the same. Not sure if adding the trail name as a fixed factor have any relationship with the problem.

Comment: I reviewd the "Logistic regression in R returning NA values" question and that solve my problem. Thanks for your help